# Represent processes in flowchart

Tags: flowchart

I want to add two processes out from the same process. How to represent that in flowchart diagram accurately?
Here what I tried to do ..
[image]

Is it right? 
Or should I connect the 2 arrows that output from (Teacher) rectangle?!

Comment: There is no flowchart diagram in UML (see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html), but there is an Activity Diagram (see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html)

Comment: Your drawing has little to do with any UML diagram. Either it's not a UML diagram (as already mentioned by @xmojmr there is no flowchart diagram in UML) and you should remove `uml` tag from your question or you would like to represent that indeed using UML but then start from reading any book about UML and learn basics.

Comment: ok , lets consider it as a normal flowchart (not a uml diagram ), because I need to draw flowchart, How can I add two processes out from the same process ?
any advice ? :)